# Strange Behaviour of Selected UITableViewCell in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am porting my application to iOS 7 and having some strange behaviour with my tableViews. When I **select a cell, the separators disappear for no apparent reason**. Not only that, but the **background image for the selected state also shifts about 1 pixel upward**, even though its frame does not indicate this. I have none of these issues with iOS 6 or older operating systems.

I define my table view the following way:

```
    statisticsTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, window.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    statisticsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    statisticsTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    //statisticsTableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero; // <- Makes app crash in iOS6 or older
    statisticsTableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    statisticsTableView.delegate = self;
    statisticsTableView.dataSource = self;
```

The cell is sub-classed and the relevant parts are the following (both regular and selected bacground images are the exact same size and appear correct in iOS6 or older, it is only iOS 7 where the selected BG image appears slightly higher):

```
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 70.0f)];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_background_corp.png"]];
    self.backgroundView = backgroundView;

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 70.0f)];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_background_corp_selected.png"]];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;
```

Now, I do know that other people had already asked this question (or, at least part of it), but none of the answers there worked for me. For further reference, I tried these "solutions" and they did **NOT** work:

```
Putting this into my didSelectrowAtIndexPath made my cells deselect. 
But, I need my selected cell to stay selected, and besides 
it looked really awkward with the blinking as swithces between states:

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

The other one:

```
Putting this into the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method 
as a return value did absolutely nothing:

    ceilf(rowHeight);
```

And finally:

```
This was my attempt to fix the background image position bug. I modified
the way I added the selected background view in the subclassed tableView cell,
but it did not do squat:

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 70.0f)];
    if (iOSVersion >= 7.0f)
    {
        backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 1.0f, 150.0f, 70.0f);
    }
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_background_corp_selected.png"]];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView;
```

Comment: I've seen this happen with the built in apple apps as well. Not every time, but often enough to notice.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug that will be addressed in a future update.

Comment: Are you using default tableview cell or are you customizing it?

Comment: Is this issue on iOS 7? If yes then try to set table view type to plain table. This might fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and what fixed it for me was to override layoutSubviews in the UITableViewCell subclass like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = self.backgroundView.frame;
}
```

The important thing is to have the `[super layoutSubviews]`call first.

By the way, I think the default behavior is intended in iOS7. If you look at the Apple Mail app, you see that the separator line also disappears when selecting a cell and that the active background is drawn where the separator line used to be.